# Get previous row's value on a MySQL view

Tags: mysql, sql, view

Assuming I have something like this :

MySQL table

```
Date        |   Val   
2013/11/22  |   2     
2013/11/23  |   4     
2013/11/25  |   12    
2013/11/30  |   28    
2013/12/02  |   2
```

I need a query to get on an other column the sum of the "current" row's value plus the previous row's value.
With the example, the result would be something like this :

```
Date        |   Value   |  Total
2013/11/22  |   2       |  2
2013/11/23  |   4       |  6          <--- Because 4+2 = 6
2013/11/25  |   12      |  16
2013/11/30  |   28      |  40
2013/12/02  |   2       |  30
```

The problem is that I can't use variables because I'm on **a view.**

How can I do this ?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: This is not easily possible with MySQL (due to it's limited SQL features)

Comment: Well, I guess I have to think of another way to do this

Comment: Yeah it is not easy but it is possible. Right now I'm over a proxy and i don't know why guys here have blocked the sqlfiddle site. When I'm at home and if no one has answered you I will try.

Comment: @Amber Ahah yes ! My bad, I counted 16 + 28.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT
t.Date,
t.Val,
COALESCE((SELECT Val FROM Table1 sq WHERE sq.Date < t.Date ORDER BY sq.Date DESC LIMIT 1), 0) + t.Val AS whatever
FROM
Table1 t
ORDER BY t.Date
```

- see it working live in an [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8c06b/2/0)

Comment: +1 Good answer, but what about you have two equal dates (e.g. 2013/11/25 value 10 and 2013/11/25 value 11). It is just a thing that I think about when I was thinking on an answer for this :)

Comment: Well, when multiple values can occur on the same date, of course the database engineer has to deal with it and use an auto_increment column or something else instead of a date column. Anyway, the OP didn't mention this potential problem, so I don't treat it as a problem.

Comment: I've made my API so that I can't have multiple values for one same day. Anyway, thank you guys for your concern :)